# Change current object into object of a "sibling" class

Tags: python, object

I have the following class:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, cfg: dict, cfg_path: str):
        pass
```

And the following two children classes:

```
class Master(Node):
    def __init__(self, cfg: dict, cfg_path: str):
        pass
```

And

```
class Client(Node):
    def __init__(self, cfg: dict, cfg_path: str):
        pass
```

At some point, a `Client` object must be able to be converted into a `Master` object. I can do this by making the program restart itself, but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

This is the main function (I stripped some of the details):

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cfg = _load_config(args.config)
    msg = "What would you like to do? Type 'help' for help."
    if cfg["type"].lower() == "client":
        n = Client(cfg, args.config)
        while True:
            print("You are a client. " + msg)
            cmd = input()
            if cmd == "help":
                pass
            elif cmd == "extend":
                n.extend()
            elif cmd == "enroll":
                n.enroll()
            elif cmd == "get_master_public_key":
                n.get_master_public_key()
            elif cmd == "lookup":
                uuid = input("Enter UUID: ")
                n.lookup(uuid)
            elif cmd == "listen":
                print("Listening...")
                n.listen()
            else:
                print("Unknown command.")
    else:
        n = Master(cfg, args.config)
        while True:
            print("You are a master. " + msg)
            # cmd = input()
            cmd = "listen"
            if cmd == "help":
                pass
            elif cmd == "extend":
                n.extend()
            elif cmd == "listen":
                print("Listening...")
                n.listen()
            else:
                print("Unknown command.")
```

As you can see, depending on a value in the config file, it will create either a `Client` or a `Master`. Now, if the client is given the `extend` command, it must be turned into a master. I can do this by updating the value in the config file to 'master' and restarting the program, but I'd like a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can't easily change the class of an object. You should write a conversion function that returns a `Master` object with the same attributes as the original `Client` object.

Comment: If you need to do this regularly, maybe subclassing isn't the right model.

Comment: Right.  You could for example, have a class method like `Master.from_client` that accepts a `Client` object and returns the equivalent `Master`.

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I have added a little more elaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First method

What you want is ability to create a Node object dynamically. Here is one way to do that:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, cfg: dict, cfg_path: str):
        pass

    def interact(self):
        while True:
            command = input("> ").strip()
            try:
                action = getattr(self, command)
                # Calls the action
                action()
                if command == "exit":
                    break
            except AttributeError:
                print(f"Unknown command: {command}")

    def exit(self):
        print("Exit")


class Client(Node):
    def help(self):
        print("Client help")

    def extend(self):
        print("Client extend")

    def lookup(self):
        uuid = input("Enter UUID: ")
        # Do something to uuid

    # Add methods for enroll, get_master_public_key, ...


class Master(Node):
    def help(self):
        print("Master help")

    # Add methods for listen, extend, ...


def create_node(cfg, path):
    """Create a node dynamically based on cfg['type']."""
    cfg_type = cfg["type"].lower()
    if cfg_type == "client":
        NodeType = Client
    elif cfg_type == "master":
        NodeType = Master
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Incorrect type: {cfg_type}")

    node = NodeType(cfg, path)
    return node


# Assume you got cfg and cfg_path elsewhere
cfg = {
    "type": "client",
    # Some other data
}
cfg_path = "some path"

node = create_node(cfg, cfg_path)
node.interact()
```

#### Notes

- The function `create_node()` will take the same parameters needed to create the node, examine its contents to determine which object to create.
- The `interact` method is the same for both types, so it should be in `Node`, the base class
- You can add more methods if needed to each class

### Second Method: Use the cmd Library

It seems your script is trying to poll the user's input and call methods within your class (extend, lookup, ...). Python comes with the `cmd` library which makes this easy.

```py
import cmd


class Node(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = "> "

    def __init__(self, cfg: dict, cfg_path: str):
        super().__init__()

    def do_exit(self, _):
        """Implement the `exit` command to exits the loop."""
        print("bye")
        return True


class Client(Node):
    def do_extend(self, _):
        """Implement the `extend` command."""
        print("Client extend")

    def do_lookup(self, uuid):
        """Implement the `lookup` command."""
        print(f"Looking up uuid: {uuid}")

    # Add methods for enroll, get_master_public_key, ...


class Master(Node):
    pass


def create_node(cfg, path):
    """Create a node dynamically based on cfg['type']."""
    cfg_type = cfg["type"].lower()
    if cfg_type == "client":
        NodeType = Client
    elif cfg_type == "master":
        NodeType = Master
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Incorrect type: {cfg_type}")

    node = NodeType(cfg, path)
    return node


# Assume you got cfg and cfg_path elsewhere
cfg = {
    "type": "client",
    # Some other data
}
cfg_path = "some path"

node = create_node(cfg, cfg_path)
node.cmdloop()
```

Here is some interaction, the prompt in this case is "> "

```
$ python using_cmd.py
> help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
exit  extend  help  lookup

> extend
Client extend
> lookup foo-bar
Looking up uuid: foo-bar
> exit
bye
```

#### Notes

- In order to handle the `extend` command, define a method `do_extend`. To handle the `lookup` command, define a method `do_lookup`, and so on
- By default, the `help` command is already implemented
- I highly recommend using this library as it handles lots of details for you, leaving you concentrating on writing what matters to your script.